# How can I display variables on the same line with SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have this code and i want to display it on the same line with text.

```
from sympy import *

c, x, L, y, a, b, E, xi, A, R, D, nu, q0, h, eta = symbols("c,x,L,y,a,b,E,xi,A,R,D,nu,q0,h,eta")
w = c * x / a * (1 - cos(2 * pi * y / b))

wx = diff(w, x)
wxx = diff(w, x, 2)

wy = diff(w, y)
wyy = diff(w, y, 2)


q = q0 * (1 - x / a)

display(w, q, wy)
```

When i display this it displays:

```
w

q

wy
```

I Want it to display w,q,wy such that i also can put in text. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Where do you get `display`? When I try to run your program, I get "NameError: name 'display' is not defined".

Comment: try in in jupyer notebook or use from IPython.display import display

Comment: I don't have a function `display` in my python distribution, and sympy doesn't either: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/py-modindex.html . Try printing with sympy's printing tools instead: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: first use `init_printing()`, the don't use `display`:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()

c, x, L, y, a, b, E, xi, A, R, D, nu, q0, h, eta = symbols("c,x,L,y,a,b,E,xi,A,R,D,nu,q0,h,eta")
w = c * x / a * (1 - cos(2 * pi * y / b))

wx = diff(w, x)
wxx = diff(w, x, 2)

wy = diff(w, y)
wyy = diff(w, y, 2)


q = q0 * (1 - x / a)

w, q, wy
```

this will display them into a tupl, inline.

**EDIT** to accomodate comment. I personally wouldn't use it, as it might creates more trouble than it's worth down the road:

```
import inspect
from IPython.display import display, Math

def edisplay(var):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    var_name = [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]
    var_name.sort()
    var_name = [v for v in var_name if v[0] != "_"]
    if len(var_name) == 0:
        raise ValueError
    lat = var_name[0] + "=" + latex(var)
    display(Math(lat))

edisplay(q)
# out: q = q0*(1 - x/a)
edisplay(w)
# out: w = c*x*(1 - cos(2*pi*y/b))/a
```

Comment: I was also looking for a way to add text to the lines. to print it out like "q = ... " with the nice sympy output. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Updated answer. To be honest, I feel like you are digging yourself a deeper and deeper rabbit hole...

Comment: Ohh i thought there could be a more eazy way to do this. Thanks alot!!